# How to select a specific entity diagram from solution explorer

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

In visual studio 2012 we can split an entity framework model into multiple diagrams. There doesn't seem to be any way to open a specific diagram from the solution explorer though. At the moment you seem to have to open the default diagram, then select the diagram you want from the model browser, leaving you with the default diagram open in its own tab as well. Have I missed something? It's not the end of the world, but it seems a fairly obvious thing to have missed. Logically I'd have expected to see each diagram as a child node of the model/edmx node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to the case that there is no better solution to this than opening the main model each time and doing it via the model browser. I tend to keep my default model empty now, to reduce the time to load it and access the model browser.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but here is an answer... as far as I know there is no alternative.

If you look in the .diagram in the Solution Explorer you can see that the single file includes both diagrams. As it is an .xml file it does not have child nodes unlike for example .cs files where you can see individual methods etc.

I usually keep the model browser open always as a tab so it's not much or a stretch to open up an alternative diagram.

Comment: Yes, that's what you have to do. My point was that I'm surprised they hadn't put special handling of it in the solution explorer - remember it doesn't need to just apply default XML file handling to it. I had hoped I'd missed something, but it appears I hadn't

Comment: No I guess you are right about not using default handling for XML but they haven't changed it since then... Maybe with the tools integration coming with EF 6 we will start to see some improvements :)